# Numeric literals prepended with `0`

Tags: ruby, number-literal

Using `insert`, I push values to an `Array` as:

```
myarray=[22,33,44]
myarray.insert(0,02)
# => [2,22,33,44]
```

If do the following, I get:

```
myarray.insert(0,020)
# => [16,2,22,33,44]
```

`020` becomes `16`? If I do the following, I get:

```
myarray.insert(0,0200)
# => [128,16,2,22,33,44]
```

`0200` becomes `128`? May I know the reason for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the number has a zero in front of it, ruby treats it as an octal number (base 8)

You can do similar with binary/hexadecimal too

```
0x20 => 32 (hexadecimal)
020 => 16 (octal)
0b10 => 2 (binary)
080 => Invalid octal digit
```

Comment: I didn't know this about Ruby.  That sucks!  `020` should be `20`.  I read further, and apparently this is pretty standard across languages.

Comment: I can see why it might be slighty counterintuitive, but the octal syntax makes it easy to use octal numbers. It shouldn't really be an issue either as

"020".to_i will give you 20. So the only place you can define it is in your source, and you shouldn't have redundant 0s in front of your numbers anyway :)

Comment: I see the benefit.  I don't think it is worth the cost.